# add css for odd rows having particular class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following markup

```
<tr>
  <td>1,1</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2,1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="add-css">
  <td>3,1</td>
</tr>
```

And I want to add background color for the odd rows which have class add-css, My ruff jQuery code is

```
$( "tr" ).filter( ":odd" )hasClass('add-css').css( "background-color", "blue" );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You missed the dot `.` for `hasClass` and `hasClass` return `boolean` value, so further chaining wont be possible that require the jQuery object. You can use class selector with the type selector.

[.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

> The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an
>   element

The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are

```
$( "tr.add-css" ).filter( ":odd" ).css( "background-color", "blue");
```

*OR*

```
$( "tr.add-css:odd" ).css( "background-color", "blue");
```

Comment: @SadamAfridi even if you was sleeping, browser was not: it shows `Uncaught SyntaxError` in console.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$( "tr:nth-child(odd)" ).each(function(index, element) {

    if($(this).hasClass('add-css')){
        $(this).css( "background-color", "blue" );
    }
});
```

or even you can do it with css using

```
tr.add-css:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:blue;
}
```